# How to connect two rigid bodies, then displace them relative to one another?

Tags: godot, godot-4

I want to temporarily connect multiple `RigidBody2D` objects in a Godot 2D scene so they move together as one rigid body, and later split them up again.

I have basically managed to do so by dynamically creating two `PinJoint2D` instances and pointing them to the two rigid bodies. This way, the two rigid bodies are now connected to what looks and behaves like one rigid body.

However, now I want to vary the relative positions of the two rigid bodies with respect to one another. How do I do this? I have tried to modify the transform/position of the `PinJoint2D` instances, but this does not appear to have any effect.